# Changing dropdown option in React doesn't apply styling targeting selected option

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I am creating a dropdown menu in React. I want all menu options to be 'tomato' colored by default, then when I select an option, I want that selected/checked option to be 'purple' colored. I have React 15.6.2.

```
class BridesmaidsNumber extends Component {
    handleChange(e) {
        console.log("change in bridesmaids number" + e);
        this.props.onUserDataChange(e.target.name, e.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        let {bridesmaids_number} = this.props.userData;
        let optionsState = bridesmaids_number == "" ? "none" : bridesmaids_number;
        return (

            <div className="cell">
                <select className={!bridesmaids_number.length ? 'placeholder-select' : ''}
                        name="bridesmaids_number"
                        id="bridesmaids_number"
                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                        value={optionsState}>
                    <option value="none" disabled>Number of Bridesmaids in the wedding</option>
                    <option value="0" checked={optionsState == 0}>Not sure yet</option>
                    <option value="1" checked={optionsState == 1}>1</option>
                    <option value="2" checked={optionsState == 2}>2</option>
                    <option value="3" checked={optionsState == 3}>3</option>

                </select>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Here is the CSS

```
  select option {
    color: purple;
  }
  select:not(:checked) {
    color: tomato;
  }

  select:checked {
    color: purple;
  }

  option:hover,
  option:focus,
  option:active,
  option:checked {
    color: purple;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first css rule kills the difference between selected and non-selected options. Change styles:

```
select option, select:not(:checked) {
  color: tomato;
}
select:checked {
  color: purple;
}
option:hover, option:focus, option:active, option:checked {
  color: purple;
}
```